# WordPress query_posts()

Tags: wordpress

Hello Im new to Wordpress , But I styled some elements, and had the recent posts in them . My question, can I have them for 5 posts repeated after each other ? thanks :)

```
<div id="main_content">
    <h2>Latest Products</h2>

    <div class="latest_products">
        <div class="group">
            <?php query_posts("post_per_page=1"); the_post(); ?>
            <h3 class="stick_note"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="pro_content">
                <div class="product_thumbnail"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END LATEST PRODUCTS -->


</div> <!-- END Main Content -->
```

Comment: Be more specific. Your question does not make any sense to someone who doesn't know what you built and why.

Comment: I have posts in my blog , and at the homepage I want to show the most recent 5 posts , this code brings me just the first. I want this whole structure repeated for each posts to get the 5 ones

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) (click for detailed info).

A full Wordpress loop is as follows:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   ...render your post here, it will keep repeating...
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Since you don't have an actual loop implemented it can only render 1 post.

Comment: I tried it , it repeated only the most recent post forever , I need the latest 5 posts to be shown , Is that possible ?

Comment: @user2381305 You should also change `query_posts("post_per_page=1")` to `query_posts("post_per_page=5")` I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
get_archives('postbypost', 5);
```

OR

```
query_posts("showposts=5");
```

This help you? Be more specific in your question.

You can find the answer in documentation of wordpress:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives

**EDIT:**

```
$args = array('numberposts' => 5, 'order'=> 'ASC');
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

**EDIT2:**

You can do:

```
$args = array('numberposts' => 5, 'order'=> 'ASC');
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $postslist as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <li>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```